# what does this error mean (jquery-1.10.2.js:5095)

Tags: javascript, jquery

its been a while since I used my website and today that i tried to use it i keep getting this error before it was working just fine i havent done any coding to my site. can anyone tell me what is wrong I also added the Jquery for the code to make more sense. 10101000101010001110010101000101010111001001010101000101011001000111000

```
Uncaught TypeError: html2canvas(...).then is not a function
at renderContent ((index):2108)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):1952)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.js:5095)
at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.10.2.js:4766)
renderContent @ (index):2108
(anonymous) @ (index):1952
dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

HTML

```
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery("#btn-Preview-Image").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    renderContent();
    jQuery("#download").removeClass("disabled");
});

if (document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image") != undefined) {
    document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
    download.onclick = downloadImage;
}

    function renderContent() {
   html2canvas(jQuery("#firstshirt"), {
   allowTaint: true,
  logging: true
   }).then(function(canvas) {
   jQuery("#previewImage").append(canvas);
   jQuery("#download").css("display", "inline");
   jQuery("#download").attr("href", jQuery("#previewImage")
   [0].children[0].toDataURL());
   });
    }



      function renderContent() {
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("firstshirt"), {
      allowTaint: true
       }).then(function(canvas) {
      result.appendChild(canvas);
      download.style.display = "inline";
      download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
      });
       }


       if (document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image") != undefined) {
       document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
       download.onclick = downloadImage

        }




           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
           <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any code that goes with all that? Have you checked out the [issues tab](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues) on the github page?

Comment: ill do my best to isolate the code that belongs to this error

Comment: do u include html2canvas related js into your page? can you show how you arrange ur js reference

Comment: Your error happened inside `renderContent`. We can't see `renderContent` function.

Comment: **Probably** the issue is that either `html2content` is not loaded, _or_ the selector used on `html2content` is invalid.  This portion of the error is fairly telling: `html2canvas(...).then` - that is saying that `html2canvas` (the function) applied to the selector `...` (omitted for some reason) would _normally_ have a function `.then` (it's a promise, presumably), but in this case, `.then` is _not a function_.  Therefore, either html2content is not loaded, or the given selector is invalid.

Comment: it seems like either some js file not included or included in improper manner

Comment: Why is `renderContent()` defined twice?

Comment: One is to display the image  when user clicks on preview and the other is to download the image

Comment: You can't have two fns with same name. They both attempt to do the same thing - one is a jQuery-ized version of the other. One or other version probably works- I can't tell which.

Comment: If you haven't been in there messing with the code, it looks like someone else has.

Comment: I haven't touched the code in months and today when I tried using it I got the error. It worked great when I left it. Here is my site https://torcdesign.com/prison45 if you do go to my site try using preview nothing happens